# One word for covered area of a house (except the garden/lawn outside covered area but inside outer boundary)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

In the area I live in, the houses are designed such that there is a covered area (with a front and back door) which contains rooms etc. and then there is a garden around it with grass and plants etc., and this is all enclosed in outer boundary wall and main gate.

I want to talk about the covered area which has the rooms; but I want to use one word for it. What would that word be?

I think words like *"building"* or *"premises"* describe everything inside the outer boundary.

Comment: What area do you live in?

Comment: The house/building is the roofed part with the rooms in. The garden/yard isn't part of the house. You could call the whole area the _premises_ or _property_.

Comment: You might refer to the area under roof, but that's not one word. And what if there's an open atrium? It sounds as if "living area" might fit, but it's not one word.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree. A _building_ has one or more rooves (for example a house with a single storey part and an attached garage) and a building or buildings (perhaps a house and detached garage) with open yards and buildings are the _premises_. Arguably a small open area completely surrounded by the building such as a light well or cloister garden might be considered to be part of the building but that doesn't apply to many buildings and is an aruguable use anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify why 'house' isn't adequate?

Comment: @Spagirl "The house is well-lit" could refer to the outside, whereas "the **indoors/interior** is well-lit" couldn't.

Comment: @DjinTonic which is why we ask for a sample sentence in single-word-requests

Comment: Sounds like an **annexe**.

Comment: You may wish to consider using one of the following: lodgings, establishment, quarters (living quarters), dwelling, abode, residence, accommodations.